How can I use ffprobe inside a batch file to detect if below 720p?
My plan is to write a recursive searching batch file, that will search for video files below 720p, store their full paths, and then at the end of the search, start upscaling those videos.
But first how can i via ffprobe detect if said file is below 720p in preset, not sure if that is the correct terminology.
Thanks.
